# What excatly are the "worlds" in provability logic?

Tags: arithmetic, modal-logic, provability

What is the interpretation of the set $W$ in a Kripke model $\mathcal{K}=\langle W,R,\phi\rangle$ of provability logic, where the $\Box$-operator stands for provability in a given arithmetic theory. What are the elements of this set?

Further what is the interpretation of the relation $R$ on the set $W$?

Neither Boolos or Smorynksi seems to give an answer to this question in their texts on the subject.

Comment: See e.g. [Modal Logic: Possible Worlds Semantics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#PosWorSem).

Comment: And see [Provability Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-provability/): "Provability logic is a *modal logic* that is used to investigate what arithmetical theories can express in a restricted language about their provability predicates. Provability logic has suitable possible worlds semantics, just like many other modal logics. As a reminder, a possible worlds model (or Kripke model) is a triple $M=⟨W,R,V⟩$..."

Comment: Possible world semantics is a mathematical tool to formalize the meaning of modal operator (possible, necessary) that intuitively express facts about what can (or cannot) be in addition to what actually is.

Comment: The key-point of PL is to formalize the *provability predicate* derived from Gödel's researches as a modal operator.